# Flutter sqflite error: Exception has occured. SqfliteDatabaseException

Tags: flutter, dart, crud, sqflite

I have a flutter application with a sqflite database, but when i want to create/add a new item it shows error [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTcJz.png)

This is my code to create a new item:

```
static Future<int> createItem(String title, String descrption, String start, String end, String location) async {
  final db = await SQLHelper.db();

  final data = {
    'title': title,
    'description': descrption,
    'start time': start,
    'end time': end,
    'location': location,
    'createdAt': DateTime.now().toString()
  };
  final id = await db.insert('items', data,conflictAlgorithm: sql.ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
  return id;
}
```

Comment: try changing "start time" to "startTime" and "end time" to "endTime".

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are not normally allowed in SQL column names, they're parsed as the end of the name and the start of the next element. In this case, "start time" (and "end time") are parsed as a column named "start", and an identifier "time" where a "," should be.

If you can't change the column names (replace " " with "_"), you can try putting "start time" and "end time" in quotes (in code: `'"start time"'` should work).